# AutoMapper returns a list with all properties 0 or null

Tags: automapper, castle-windsor

For some reason AutoMapper gives me a list of the type I need, where all properties are 0 or null. When I debug on data I see my list with all object and properties containing data. But .Map() gives me a list with no data in the properties (but the correct amount of objects). I'm new to AutoMapper, but this does seem very weird. Any suggestions?

```cs
public static IMapper Initialize()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<PlantSelectResult, IPlant>()
                .ForMember(
                dest => dest.description, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.description));

        });

        return new Mapper(config);
    }
```

And my DataProvider:

```cs
public IEnumerable<IPlant> GetPlants()
        {
            using (var dbCtx = new DataClasses1DataContext(_connectionString.String))
            {
                var data = dbCtx.PlantSelect().ToList();
                return automapper.Map<List<PlantSelectResult>, IPlant[]>(data);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize I had removed set; on the properties. Fixing the interfaces so they were settable fixed the problem.